# Ignore git directory

Tags: git, github

We're working on `erlang` and `chicagoboss` for some projects. ChicagoBoss is a framework. When we create a `project1` it becomes like this:

```
.
├── cb_admin
├── ChicagoBoss
├── ebin
├── project1
└── vagrant
```

And we did `git init` for `project1` only. Later after finishing `project1`, we created another `project2` with `git init` in it.

```
├── cb_admin
├── ChicagoBoss
├── ebin
├── project1
├── project2
└── vagrant
```

Sometimes, When I work in `project1` git status shows me following output:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../project2/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Even though there is nothing to commit in `project2`. Why untracked files appear? However to verify I went in my `project2` dir and did a `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ./

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So to ignore the line for local only, I ran the following command without success:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged ./
Ignoring path gift_tax/
```

Can one help me about

- What is `./` appearing there?
- How can I ignore it on local only, changes should not reflect to my remote directory.

Comment: are you git init on folder `/project1` or on root folder? because if you git init on folder `/project`, it should contains all files or folders that located on that folder only. not like your git status message, it says `../project2/`. so i guess you git init on root folder

Comment: @AryWibowo - Oh Okay, so someone from our team, might have done on root folder.

Comment: @AryWibowo - Do you know, What is `./` appearing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`../project2/` (from project1 status) and `./` (in project2 status) are consistent with a `git init` done on root folder (and no on project1 or project2)

> Oh Okay, so someone from our team, might have done on root folder

Look for a `.git` folder. It is probably in /, not in `project1` or `project2`

> Do you know, What is `./` appearing there?

Because `project2` is not added to the repo which is in `/`.

---

Possible solution (warning: it would lose the current history)

- delete the `/.git` folder,
- do a `git init` in `project1` and `project2`,
- in each project, add and commit.

Comment: Got the reason why it is appearing!. deleting worked with no history anymore which can be ignored in our case. Thank you